# How do I update one file in a jar without repackaging the whole jar?

Tags: java, jar

I have a .jar file called myfile.jar. Inside this jar file is a folder called images. Inside this folder called images, I have an image called hi.png. I want to update that image with a new version of that image, which is also called hi.png. I do not want to extract all of the files from the single jar file and then repackage them, I just want to update the image. So, I go to command line as usual, type a few lines of code, and then I do this command:

```
jar uf myfile.jar -C images hi.png
```

What I hoped to do with that command was to replace the old hi.png with the new hi.png. But, it gives me this error:

```
images\hi.png : no such file or directory
```

What do I do to fix this?

Extra info: I can not use something like WinRAR, I have to do this with command line.

Comment: **jar** files are also **zip** files, so the feature packed [zip tool](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm) can operate on them.  If you're on anything non-Windows, you should have it already installed.  (I think MacOS would have it, but I can't verify.)

Comment: Not sure what your design is here... but 7Zip has a great command line  support. Just be careful, the jar specification is picky about the exact type of zip. Secondly, you could probably use an expanded jar if this is web based. And... if it isn't web based (single client) why not just load the image from ./images/hi.png. TL;DR; Do it the easy way, if you're swapping on a filesystem use the filesystem.

Comment: What directory are you doing this in (and where are images and hi.png relative to your cwd)?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand its on all versions of OS X

Comment: 1) I'd generally use Ant or another build tool to build the Jars lazily (only when resources are updated) 2) Since Zip brings little benefit to most media types (at least sound, video & images), I'd also generally put them in a separate Jar with no compression.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`-C` is changing the local directory, and is looking for `hi.png` there.  It's not controlling where you're trying to inject it into the JAR file.

I would try making a new directory called `images`, moving your local `hi.png` into that, making `images` a child directory of your current working directory, then just run this:

```
jar uf myfile.jar images\hi.png
```

Comment: It still gives me that error images\hi.png : no such file or directory

Comment: I just actually tested this, and it is working as expected.  Make sure your working directory is the directory containing "images".  Can you show an export of your command prompt showing the directory structure and the exact commands you're attempting?

Comment: +1 for joev's comment.  Since I saw the "images\hi.png" in the error, I guess I assumed Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I completely did something different from what you said, everything is working fine now, Thanks so much!

Comment: I know it's an old question-answer, but I find it not working for spring boot runnable jar replacing "BOOT-INF/classes/logback-spring.xml" file, it gives me "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile"

Comment: the most important move is making sure you have the same directory structure on the working directory!

Comment: This is quite strange! The jar tool ought to be more intuitive.

Comment: This works for me for simple .war files manually generated but, when using a war file created by Spring, this command line replaces the whole original contents by the added hi.png file

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to do is using **7-zip** software. For

1. **Editing** a file:

   - Open the jar file 7-zip | open archive
   - goto the file e.g. /Meta-Inf/xyz.conf
   - right mouse click and select '*open inside*' option
   - edit the file and save the file
   - close the 7-zip console and it's done.
2. For **adding/replacing/removing** a file.

   - Follow the first two steps till you reach the desired folder.
   - **Removing**: delete the file
   - **Adding**: Drag and drop the file to the 7-zip console.
   - close the console and it's done.

Comment: Thanks, It is the easiest and simple way to update jar file without repackaging.

Comment: if 'open inside' option doesn't open file, then click on 'Edit' option directly. It will open file in notepad, change it and then save.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `jar -uf sample.jar [path in jar file]target-file`

Answer (score 6):

You can use "jar" command line to extract your file and create a new jar file.

More detail you can check out from [how  to replace a image in a jar file](https://medium.com/@chase_wu/how-to-replace-a-image-in-a-jar-file-on-mac-aade48b78cf8)

```sh
# create a new folder
mkdir contents
# extract jar file
jar xf example-1.5.jar
# Then you'll get a list of new files from jar
ls
# update your images in it
# create a new jar
jar cf example-1.5.jar *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend Spring Boot App (e.g. for e2e testing purposes), this one worked for me:

part of Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./libs/*.jar /BOOT-INF/lib/
RUN jar u0f /app.jar /BOOT-INF/lib/*.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

Jar files are similar to zip files. When you edit a zip file, vim unzips it and allows you to edit files inside of the zip file. Simply navigate over the file and press enter, and you will be able to edit files inside of the archive.

(Assuming you have `unzip` available, e.g. `yum install -y unzip` on CentOS)

`vim my.jar`

Comment: A .jar file is not a text file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip! I did not know this about vim and it was the perfect tip when I needed change some property-settings within a jar-file!

Comment: Which statement makes you think that `A .jar file is a text file` ?

Comment: @user207421 so what? Vim has a plugin for working with zip files built-in